# Support library issue to use "android.support.v4.provider.DocumentFile"

Tags: android, usb, fragment, android-support-library

In my application i need to use `android.support.v4.provider.DocumentFile` which is available in recent support jar file.

To implement this functionality i have removed my old support jar file from project and added recent dowloaded jar file(updated in sdk upto latest till now).

Now when i run my application it crashes by giving below exception.

```
 "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference"
```

Could some one suggest why application is crashing if i use recent jar. Below is my app min and target sdk version

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: gradle file please

Comment: I am using eclipse for my project. Let me know what info you need from manifest

Comment: Just for info my application uses the Fragments in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself found the issue.

In recent days the api's of the fragments changed it seems. When application is trying to add child fragment from main fragment it need to make use of **getChildFragmentManager()** instead of **getFragmentManager()**.

Below are the changes made.

**OLD**

`FragmentA fragment = (FragmentA)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_a_id);`

**FIX**

`FragmentA fragment = (FragmentA)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_a_id);`